# CSS transform-origin + scale triggers offset while zooming to cursor point

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, diagram

I'm trying to implement zoom in/out functionality for regular div elements (not canvas) by using transform origin and scale CSS properties. Everything works as expected, except that after changing the cursor's coordinates and then resizing, there is some offset. After that, zooming in and out works fine. The issue repeats after moving the cursor. The larger the zoom level, the greater the offset. I'm having difficulty identifying the pattern and adjusting the values I pass to transform-origin.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-teguvc?file=script.js

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const map = document.querySelector('.map');

const scaleStep = 0.2;
let scale = 1;

container.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!event.ctrlKey) {
    return;
  }

  event.deltaY < 0 ? (scale += scaleStep) : (scale -= scaleStep);

  const originX = container.scrollLeft + event.clientX;
  const originY = container.scrollTop + event.clientY;

  map.style.transformOrigin = `${originX}px ${originY}px`;
  map.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
});
```

My goal is to get rid of this cursor "jump".

Comment: @Yogi I've tried. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to adjust the transform-origin, you might want to try adjusting the scroll position of the container after each zoom.

```
container.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!event.ctrlKey) {
    return;
  }

  const rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  const offsetX = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const offsetY = event.clientY - rect.top;

  if (event.deltaY < 0) {
    scale += scaleStep;
  } else {
    scale -= scaleStep;
  }

  map.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;

  const newScrollLeft = offsetX * scale - rect.width / 2;
  const newScrollTop = offsetY * scale - rect.height / 2;

  container.scrollLeft = newScrollLeft;
  container.scrollTop = newScrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work as expected. It doesn't scale to the cursor point but to the element's center.